# How can I modify the dependent: :destroy query for has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

I have a model called `Family` and it has a `has_many` relationship to `Parent`:

```
class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parents, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

When a user deletes a `Family`, it should delete any associated `Parent`.

There's one major hitch: I have a multi-tenant environment (using the Apartment gem) and parents are in the public schema. Thus, I need to select only parents **in the same account** should be deleted.

Right now, when destroy is called on the `Family` I get:

`SELECT "public"."users".* FROM "public"."users" WHERE "public"."users"."type" IN ('Parent') AND "public"."users"."family_id" = $FAMILY_ID`

I need it to be:

`SELECT "public"."users".* FROM "public"."users" WHERE "public"."users"."type" IN ('Parent') AND "public"."users"."family_id" = $FAMILY_ID AND "public"."users"."account_id" = $CURRENT_ACCOUNT_ID`

Is there a way to override the `Family.destroy` method so that it only selects the right associated records?

Comment: You can add a scope here to filter `has_many :parents, ->() { <some-condition>}, :dependent => :destroy`. In that way you can delete the records   conditionally. Pass the `CURRENT_ACCOUNT_ID` as an argument to scope lambda.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Is that possible if `CURRENT_ACCOUNT_ID` is only available in the controller since it's part of the request?

Comment: I didn't get you. :) But you can pass the value like `Family.parents(CURRENT_ACCOUNT_ID).destroy_all` from any where.

Comment: @ArupRakshit OK, but how do I get the `has_many :parents, :dependent => :destroy` to do that? Should I just remove `dependent: :destroy` and do an after callback on `Family.destroy`? Or override `Family.destroy`?

Comment: You don't need to override method, you will just call it like I did above. By this `:dependent => :destroy` you are telling AR, to delete the childs you get as a result from the call `family.parents(CURRENT_ACCOUNT_ID).destroy_all`, where `family` is an instance of `Family`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I went with. I removed the `dependent: :destroy` clause from the `has_many :parents` relationship in the `family.rb` model. Instead, I perform the cascading delete in the Family controller's `destroy` action:

```
def destroy
  @family = Family.find(params[:id])
  authorize @family

  parents = @family.parents.for_account(current_account.id)

  @family.destroy

  if @family.destroyed?
    parents.destroy_all
  end

  redirect_to families_path
end
```

I had to do this in the controller because the controller is aware of the `current_account` while the model is not. The `for_account` method on the Parent model looks like this:

```
scope :for_account, -> (id) { where(:account_id => id) }
```